# Post image returned from UIImagePickerController to PHP in Swift

Tags: swift

So basically, I am trying make it possible for the user to take a photo using UIImagePickerController and for that photo to then be uploaded to a PHP script that will store the image. The PHP script is as follows:

```
 <?php
 $target_dir = "/data/test/pics/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
     if($check !== false) {
         echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
         $uploadOk = 1;
     } else {
         echo "File is not an image.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
     }
 }
 // Check if file already exists
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
     echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 // Check file size
 if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
     echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 // Allow certain file formats
 if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
 && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
     echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
     $uploadOk = 0;
 }
 // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
     echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
 // if everything is ok, try to upload file
 } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     } else {
         echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

And in Swift the user can use the UIImagePickerController to take the photo:

```
func grabAndLoadUserPhoto(img: AnyObject)
    {

        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageThumbnail.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        //TODO: Upload image to server
    }
```

However, Im not quite sure how to post that image to the php script. What I have so far is the following:

```
func uploadUserPhoto(){
        guard let url = NSURL(string: "https://test.mysite.com/upload_photo.php") else { return }
        let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    }
```

However, I dont really know how to supply the actual photo, and Im not quite sure how to do the actual upload other than the fact that I can use a `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest` to handle it. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, you try [`func uploadTaskWithRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest,
                  fromFile fileURL: NSURL) -> NSURLSessionUploadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:) first an test how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Attach image data from request.

`request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(fields, filePathKey: "image", data: fileData, fileName:"image.jpg", boundary: boundary)`

`func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: NSDictionary?, filePathKey: String?, data: NSData?, fileName: String?, boundary: String) -> NSData 
{`

```
    let body = NSMutableData()

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }
    if data != nil {

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n")
        var mimetype = "application/octet-stream"
        if let fileNameWithExtension:String = fileName {
            let pathExtension = fileNameWithExtension.pathExtension
            if let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension as NSString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() {
                if let aMimetype = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() {
                    mimetype  = aMimetype as NSString as String
                }
            }
        }
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(data!)
        body.appendString("\r\n")
    }

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    return body
}
```

try it. i think its better ans for you.